# Multiple column mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, multiple-columns

I have a big data table with 100+ columns and I would like to change values in selected ones. I would like to select the columns by column names.

```
df <- data.frame(
  xy_Date = c("2018-12-03","2019-01-02","2019-02-03"),
  ab_Date = c("2018-05-03","2019-10-02","2019-12-03"),
  names = c("Kevin", "Mark", "Jon"))
```

I would like change columns xy_Date and ab_Date from character type to date.

```
library(dplyr)    
df %>% mutate(across(grep("Date", names(df)), ~ as.Date(as.character(.x), "%Y-%m-%d ")))
```

But is there a solution with base R?

Comment: Although your `dplyr` code works but in `dplyr` there are functions like `starts_with`/`contains` etc to select columns. Here you can do `df %>% mutate(across(contains('Date'), as.Date))` to get the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, you can use `lapply` -

```
cols <- grep("Date", names(df))
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], as.Date)
df

#     xy_Date    ab_Date names
#1 2018-12-03 2018-05-03 Kevin
#2 2019-01-02 2019-10-02  Mark
#3 2019-02-03 2019-12-03   Jon

str(df)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ xy_Date: Date, format: "2018-12-03" "2019-01-02" "2019-02-03"
# $ ab_Date: Date, format: "2018-05-03" "2019-10-02" "2019-12-03"
# $ names  : chr  "Kevin" "Mark" "Jon"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  xy_Date = c("2018-12-03","2019-01-02","2019-02-03"),
  ab_Date = c("2018-05-03","2019-10-02","2019-12-03"),
  names = c("Kevin", "Mark", "Jon"))   

new_col_df = df %>% mutate_at(vars(contains('Date')),as.Date)
str(new_col_df)

## Output
# str(new_col_df)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ xy_Date: Date, format: "2018-12-03" "2019-01-02" "2019-02-03"
# $ ab_Date: Date, format: "2018-05-03" "2019-10-02" "2019-12-03"
#  $ names  : chr  "Kevin" "Mark" "Jon"
```

Answer (score 1):

IN `base R`

```
df[endsWith(names(df), "Date")] <- lapply(df[endsWith(names(df), "Date")], as.Date)
```

-output

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ xy_Date: Date, format: "2018-12-03" "2019-01-02" "2019-02-03"
 $ ab_Date: Date, format: "2018-05-03" "2019-10-02" "2019-12-03"
 $ names  : chr  "Kevin" "Mark" "Jon"
```